# How to add date picker (calendar) in filter in Admin grid ui component

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

[image]

I have a custom grid in Admin using UI component.
I want to add calendar as input selector in filter like date of birth/customer since( **NOT** from/to)

Just a single input box with date selector

I tried `Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date` but it added a **from/to**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you explain why you need only one value instead of from-to? I think from-to offers a more elegant way to filter the grid data than a simple date picker. If you want to filter by an exact date, fill in the same value in 'from' and 'to'.

Comment: @Marius in my custom table we have date column and we need to filter on that dates. that's why need a single date picker.

Comment: but you can still filter by a single date if you have a from-to. but as bonus you get the interval filtering also. I don't think it's worth the trouble